# How do I make sure Visual Studio 2017 references are not missing with .gitignore?

Tags: git, reference, visual-studio-2017, nuget, gitignore

[image]

We are using Visual Studio 2017. I'm new here, but somehow my system has very different references than the older developers machine, but git shows no differences when we both are on the latest checkouts. The left side shows the working system, the right side shows the system after NuGet did whatever it did to update packages.

I didn't change the references manually, NuGet update wizards (or something) did.

Changing the references doesn't show anything in the changed files to be staged. I'm guessing this has to do with ".gitignore" file.  Does anyone know what should or should not be included? I haven't worked at a Microsoft shop for about 10 years so I'm used to VI and lower level C/C++ and Linux environments and I'm a bit lost on which menu or registry or whatever contains the information.

Right off the bat I see "lib" and "packages" are not included but those appear to be the same on both computers. ".vs" and ".git" have thousands of files different, but I'm guessing those should not be shared.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>NuGet Package Manager</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd>, then check the *Package Management* is `Packages.config` instead of `PackageReference`

[image]

Then try to re-check out the project in your visual studio.